# How to use media keys in GNOME Shell with local and web media players

Tags: configuration, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome-shell

Whenever I open a media player (i.e. Rhythmbox, Banshee...), I am able to control them with the media keys (play/pause, next song, etc.). Now I would like to pass those media keys to my web browser as well, so I can control a web player.

I can just disable the "Sound and media" shortcuts in the GNOME Shell's keyboard configuration menu. In the example bellow, I have disabled the play/pause shortcut and, therefore, when I press the play/pause key, it is correctly being sent to my web browser:

[image]

But the problem is that this way, although I can control the web player, I can not control the local media player anymore! As I said, I would like to be able to control both of them.

So, what I guess is that GNOME Shell is catching those media keys and searching for those applications that thinks could use them (i.e. local music players), but as it doesn't find any, it just does nothing.

Is there a way to change this behavior? i.e. being able to use the media keys to control both the local media player and the web player with the same keys.

Comment: The problem here is that gnome-settings-daemon grabs the media keys so if your browser isn't registered as a music application (which it certainly isn't) those keys won't work with your web player. I don't think there's a trivial workaround...

Comment: A few years have passed and now the browsers do register as media applications (chromium by default, Firefox needs media.hardwaremediakeys.enabled in about:config). Unfortunately g-s-d only controls the first app that appears, not the last one that played. https://github.com/icasdri/mpris2controller should help solve this issue. I published a detailed article about how this all works yesterday: https://work.lisk.in/2020/05/06/linux-media-control.html

Comment: @TomášJanoušek Thanks for sharing. I hope it gets integrated or fixed upstream some day! ^^